# Webpack failed to compile react code after upgrade to node v8 (on Ubuntu 16)

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, webpack

After upgrading from `node v7` to `node v8`, `webpack` failed to compile my `react` code.

It said that some `node_modules` are not found. Note: This issue does not happen on Windows.

I tried several ways from refreshing node cache & `npm_modules` to double-checking `$NODE_PATH`, but still failed to make it work. Looks like an compatibility issue of `node v8` and `webpack` (or some ES6 syntax).

Temporarily I reverted back to `node v7` to make it work.

Does anyone encounter this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you install a new Node version then you need to make sure that you install all modules that you want installed globally using that new version (you need to have both `node` and `npm` in your PATH with that new version **first** before any other version of `node` and `npm` that you might have in your PATH or this will likely not work as expected). Then you need to rebuild all locally installed modules (you may need to remove `node_modules` directory in some cases to make sure that everything is built from scratch).

One issue that is quite common when you have multiple Node versions installed from the binary packages (using either binary tarballs or nvm etc.) is that the `npm` that gets installed has a general shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env node` instead of a specific path like `#!/opt/node-v8.0.0/bin/node` which would be the case if you built Node from the sources yourself.

This means that you can sometimes go into trouble by running `npm` with global path that would use the wrong version of Node, leading to some issues that can be hard to notice.

The least problematic Node installation in my experience is building it from sources, installing in a versioned directory and explicitly adding it to PATH before installing the modules globally, before local npm install and before running the project that you want to be using that specific Node version. That way you can make sure that you're not using any files that could be left overs from older versions, like would be the case with installing under a common `/usr/local` prefix.

You can take a look at my tutorial for more details and other options to install Node:

- https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a

In general what you described is usually caused by clashing installations of Node.

Comment: Thank you so much @rsp. I tried this: completely uninstall and remove everything of node v7 > install node v8 from scratch (using apt-get as official installation guideline) > remove completely `node_module` > `npm install`. But it still failed. Let me give a try to install from source then. Since it's production server so I cannot try it immediately now. But thank you for your help.